# join to dataframe with substrings and sorting

Tags: python, pandas, merge, substring

I wish to appen some data from a dataframe to another.
the problem is I need to build a key to be able to make map the values between the two dataframe.
so I built an example, with df1 has a column "RAW". this column contains a string that needs to be split, first 3 characters from left and 3 from the right, then sorted alphabetically. meaning if "RAW" is "RTYdfhgvisdhQWE" the string that I want to use is QWERTY.
and then it needs to be mapped to the proper CODE in df2 using the CODE and the DATE.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["RAW", "DATE", "VALUE"])

df1.at[0, 'RAW'] = 'QWE/RTY'
df1.at[0, 'DATE'] = '2012-01-01'
df1.at[0, 'VALUE'] = 'TEST0'
df1.at[1, 'RAW'] = 'RTY/AZE'
df1.at[1, 'DATE'] = '2015-06-11'
df1.at[1, 'VALUE'] = 'TEST1'

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["CODE", "DATE", "RES"])
df2.at[0, 'CODE'] = 'QWERTY'
df2.at[0, 'DATE'] = '2012-03-01'
df2.at[0, 'RES'] = 1.1
df2.at[0, 'CODE'] = 'QWERTY'
df2.at[0, 'DATE'] = '2012-01-01'
df2.at[0, 'RES'] = 1.3
df2.at[1, 'CODE'] = 'AZERTY'
df2.at[0, 'DATE'] = '2012-06-11'
df2.at[1, 'RES'] = 1.4


def buildcodefromrow(mystring):
    return [ mystring[0:3] + mystring[4:3] if  mystring[0:2] < mystring[4:6] else  mystring[4:6] + mystring[0:2]]

df1['BUILTCODE'] = buildcodefromrow(df1['RAW'])
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2,  left_on=['BUILTCODE', 'DATE'], right_on=['CODE', 'DATE'])
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `buildcodefromrow` function to the following:

```
def buildcodefromrow(mystring):
    return mystring[0:3] + mystring[4:] if  mystring[0:3] < mystring[4:] else  mystring[4:] + mystring[0:3]
```

and the `BUILTCODE` row in df1 can be acheived using:

```
df1['BUILTCODE'] = df1['RAW'].apply(buildcodefromrow)
```

the merged df1 should look like:

```
    RAW      DATE       VALUE   BUILTCODE  CODE     RES
0   QWE/RTY 2012-01-01  TEST0   QWERTY     QWERTY   1.3
1   RTY/AZE 2015-06-11  TEST1   AZERTY     AZERTY   1.4
```

If this is not the output you expect please edit your question with the expected output.
Thanks

Comment: all right, apply does the job. regarding the function i used the code i think to get the last 3 char it's better. thank you! return mystring[0:3] + mystring[-3:] if  mystring[0:3] < mystring[-3:] else  mystring[-3:] + mystring[0:3]